# How to set chroot for SFTP under Ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, chroot

Ubuntu 8.04 LTS comes with OpenSSH 4.7, before the ChrootDirectory parameter was introduced.  How can I upgrade OpenSSH to 4.9+?  Alternatively, without upgrading OpenSSH, how can I set chroot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rssh](http://dragontoe.org/rssh/) (restricted shell) exists on 8.04 and it can be used to setup a an account that is restricted to sftp and/or scp a specific folder.